# Angular v1 - Module's config not called via Lazyload

Tags: oclazyload, angular1.6

*Lazyload Config in Parent App*

`{
    name: "lazyload-module",
    files: ["http://link_to_lazyload_module_js"],
    reconfig: true,
    rerun: true
},`

*Module Code to be LazyLoaded*

`

(function() {
    var __MODULE_NAME = "lazyload-module";

```
var app = function(angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module(__MODULE_NAME, ["oc.lazyload"]).config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            debug: true,
            events: true,
            modules: [{
                   name : 'module1_in_lazyload_module',
                   files : ["resource_link_11","resource_link_12"]
            },{
                   name : 'module2_in_lazyload_module',
                   files : ["resource_link_21","resource_link_22"]
            }]
        });
    }]);

    angular.module(__MODULE_NAME, __DEPS["module_deps"]).run(function($ocLazyLoad){

        $ocLazyLoad.load(["module1_in_lazyload_module","module2_in_lazyload_module"]).then(function (data) {

        });
    });

    return angular.module(__MODULE_NAME);
};

if ((typeof window !== "undefined" && window !== null ? window.angular : void 0) != null) {
    app(window.angular);
} else if (typeof require === "function") {
    var angular = require("angular");
    app(angular);
} else {
    throw new Error("Could not find angular on window nor via require()");
}

if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
    module.exports = __MODULE_NAME;
}
```

}).call(this);

`

**Issue** 
the config and run in the **lazyload-module** is not getting called when the module itself is loaded via lazyload from parent app.

What is the issue/mistake here ?  Basically what am trying to do is recursively lazyload modules on demand and not everything in the parent app.

Config and run of **lazyload-module** is  called when this is directly loaded in Parent App

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/iJrGdtQ2iOaA6jYIWOCS/    Plunker demo,  couldnt figure from where the console error is coming from